# Where should I type the second "print" function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can't figure out why this code doesn't work.

```py
for letter in name:
    print('give me', letter)
print('what did we get?', name)
```

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code should work as long as you have "name" defined. This is the output that I get:

```
name=["lisa", "maria"]
for letter in name:
    print('give me', letter)
print('what did we get?', name)

> [out] give me lisa 
> give me maria 
> what did we get? ['lisa', 'maria']
```

If you press tab and indent the second print to within inside the for loop your result would look like this:

```
name=["lisa", "maria"]
for letter in name:
    print('give me', letter)
    print('what did we get?', letter)

> [out] give me lisa  
> what did we get? lisa  
> give me maria  
> what did we get? maria
```

Comment: If `name` were undefined the error would be *NameError: name 'name' is not defined*.

Comment: and why is name an array of strings here instead of a string? It rather looks like the OP wants to print each letter of a name, followed by the whole name

Answer (score 3):

Only reason this would give a syntax error is that you write it directly in the console, in that case just add an empty line after the loop:

```
>>> for letter in name:
...    print('give me', letter)
...
>>> print('what did we get?', name)
```